# MySql - how to automatically implicitly trim all fields in select queries

Tags: php, mysql, settings, trim

I have some databases with trimmed data and other databases without trimmed data.

I need to query these databases, also with joins, treating all fields of all tables as trimmed.

I know that the simplest way is to use the MySQL's `TRIM` function directly in all queries for each field, but by doing this I need an exorbitant amount of time to change all my queries.

Also, I prefer an approach that let me do it in one single point to affect all my actual and future queries on these databases.

Edit: 
By trimming the whole databases can't solve my problem because some data used in queries come from external sources, which aren't trimmed.

There is a solution to achieve this?

Some info:

- MySQL version `4.5.4`
- PHP 7
- OS Ubuntu
- I can't update the MySQL version

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you write to the database? In that case, fix the data and make sure no untrimmed data gets in again by fixing the inputs.

Comment: This can't solve my problem because some data used in queries come from external source where data isn't trimmed...

Comment: If it's a MySQL database, you could define an insert trigger so that any data inserted will be trimmed on creation.

Comment: @NigelRen, that does not solve the problem because the problme isn't with the INSERTs but with datas becoming from different sources... I tell it in my question.